# The Author of a Note

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

After finding this note, I've pretty much gone to the ends of the earth to find the author's name. Maybe you can help me?

> Suppose I want my room to be a weird
> color. Something uncommon, like purple.
> Navy's also a nice shade and with hints
> of forest green, it would look really nice.
>
> Old Man Jenkins missed a turn and made us
> late, but eventually, we got to the movie.

Hint:

> This note seems extremely inconsistent.

Comment: I am sad that the last line is 3 beats longer than the first 5...